# ios google chrome jquery mobile dialog close eveny makes browser backtrack

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile

has anyone run into any problems with jquery mobile in Chrome on iOS devices where the dialog close event actually causes the browser to backtrack as if the user hit the 'back' button?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have. I still unsure why jqm behaves differently in Google Chrome for iOS